# how do I interpret this number?

Tags: video, camcorder

can someone explain this numbers please?, what means equivalent?
Focal Length 4.25-42.5mm, 35mm equivalent 30.4-305mm
thanks for your help

Comment: This may be better migrating to Photography

Comment: Here's a relevant question at photo.stackexchange.com about focal length and angle of view: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5917/what-is-angle-of-view-in-photography

Answer (score 1):

From the wikipedia entry on [focal length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_length):

> Due to the popularity of the 35 mm standard, camera–lens combinations
>   are often described in terms of their 35 mm equivalent focal length,
>   that is, the focal length of a lens that would have the same angle of
>   view, or field of view, if used on a full-frame 35 mm camera. Use of a
>   35 mm-equivalent focal length is particularly common with digital
>   cameras, which often use sensors smaller than 35 mm film, and so
>   require correspondingly shorter focal lengths to achieve a given angle
>   of view, by a factor known as the crop factor.

Comment: good explanation,thanks. I my camera says 4.25-42.5, that means that my wider angle would be 4.25mm? that seems too wide, I am sure I am getting something wrong

Comment: Well, yes.  The wide angle on your camera is 4.25mm. But since your sensor is smaller than that of a 35mm camera, this is equivalent to a 30.4mm lens on a 35mm camera.  Alternatively, when your lens is fully zoomed in, it's focal distance is 42.5mm, which is equivalent to 305mm on a 35mm camera.